# How do I read bot DMs and forward it to a channel using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that recieves DMs and forwards the message to a specific channel in a server along with the username and user id of whoever sent the DM. Here's what I've tried. It doesn't seem to work, although I think there's a possibility that the rest of my code may be affecting it.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(714242239215304745)
    if message.guild is None and message.author != client.user:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Support requested!',
            description = '{}' .format(message.content),
            color = discord.Color.from_rgb(r=159, g=255, b=255)
            )
        embed.set_footer(text='Requested by {} | ID-{}' .format(message.author, message.author.id))
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        print("Support requested by {} | ID-{}!" .format(message.author, message.author.id))
        print("Content: '{}'." .format(message.content))
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

The rest of my code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/F4R96bYR).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `message.channel == message.author.dm_channel`, and f-strings opposed to `.format()`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = client.get_channel(714242239215304745) # are you sure this channel exists?
    if message.channel == message.author.dm_channel: # do not use guild == None, as group dms might satisfy this, and you can't message yourself, no need to check client user
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Support requested!',
            description = f'{message.content}',
            color = 0x9fffff
            )
        embed.set_footer(text=f'Requested by {message.author.display_name} | ID-{message.author.id}')
        await channel.send(embed=embed)
        print("Support requested by {} | ID-{}!" .format(message.author, message.author.id))
        print("Content: '{}'." .format(message.content))
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Hmmm, it still doesn't seem to work. If it matters, I tried the exact same code as I had posted before and it worked perfectly fine. Afterward when I added more code , it had just stopped working. I think something may have interfered, although I have no idea what it is. Do you mind checking it for me? https://pastebin.com/F4R96bYR

Comment: It seems like you have defined `on_message()` multiple times, and that can cause problems. My code is the first definition, and your second definition overwrites the first definition, so nothing in my code will execute.

Comment: You should delete the second `on_message` definition, leaving only the code